# Return 5 Newest Articles for Each Category in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's say I have a table `Articles` on a SQL Server 2008 database with the columns `ID INT, Title VARCHAR(100), CatID INT, Posted DATETIME`.

To get the 5 newest articles for a particular category, I can do this.

```
SELECT TOP (5) * FROM Articles WHERE CatID = @CatID ORDER BY Posted DESC
```

But what if I want the 5 newest articles for each category? I know I can repeat the query above for each category, but is there any way to do a single query that will return the 5 newest articles for each category?

**EDIT:**

Here's is the actual query I'm using to return the 5 newest articles with the section @SectionID. According to the actual terminology I'm using, it's the "section" I'm grouping by, not "category".

```
SELECT TOP (5) *
FROM Article
    INNER JOIN Subcategory on Article.ArtSubcategoryID = Subcategory.SubID
    INNER JOIN Category on Subcategory.SubCatID = Category.CatID
    INNER JOIN section ON Category.CatSectionID = Section.SecID
WHERE (Section.SecID = @SectionID)
ORDER BY Article.ArtUpdated DESC
```

**EDIT 2:**

And here's the query I came up with based on comments here. Seems to work okay.

```
SELECT  *
FROM (
    SELECT Article.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SecID ORDER BY ArtUpdated DESC) AS rn
    FROM Article
        INNER JOIN Subcategory on Article.ArtSubcategoryID = Subcategory.SubID
        INNER JOIN Category on Subcategory.SubCatID = Category.CatID
        INNER JOIN section ON Category.CatSectionID = Section.SecID
) q
WHERE rn <= 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CatId ORDER BY Posted DESC) AS rn
        FROM    Articles
        ) q
WHERE   rn <= 5
```

Comment: @Martin: mwa-ha-ha! I have a macro bound for such questions!

Comment: @Quassnoi: This seems the most straight forward (although I don't understand all of it). But I also have a bunch of joins in my real-world query (and the category is part of one of the other tables). But I can't seem to figure out where the joins go. I can't seem to get the right results. A little more help?

Comment: @Jonathan: I would start with posting the joins (in a new question).

Comment: @Quassnoi: Sorry about that--I was trying to keep things simple but failed. I've added the actual query for getting all the articles in one section. I added it to the end of my question.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Based on your answer, I seem to have this working. I posted my solution in my question. Would appreciate any constructive criticism if I didn't use the best technique. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CatID ORDER BY Posted DESC) 
AS Rownum,*
FROM Articles )

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE Rownum <= 5
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this. Why does the query start with `;` and what does CTE do? Googling, I guess you are talking about Common Table Expressions?

Comment: a cte has to be its own statement, if there is nothing before you don't need the ;, otherwise you need to terminate the statement before and ; does that